# Need help using an HTML select box on IE8

Tags: html, button, menu, internet-explorer-8, submit

I used the following HTML code to create a simple drop down menu. (Actully got it from this site by doing a search).

But the issue I'm having is the submit ("Go!") button works in every other browser but IE 8-9. Even works on IE 10 on a Windos Phone. CAn somebody PLEASE tell me what needs to be changed to get it working? 
Thanks.

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="Game Results">
<select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_name" style="width: 40% !important;">
<option value="" selected>Select Game</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=60&Itemid=82">Week 1</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=61&Itemid=82">Week 2</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=62&Itemid=82">Week 3</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=63&Itemid=82">Week 4</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=64&Itemid=82">Week 5</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=65&Itemid=82">Week 6</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=66&Itemid=82">Week 7</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=67&Itemid=82">Week 8</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=68&Itemid=82">Week 9</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=69&Itemid=82">Week 10</option>
<option value="http://thealamedapirates.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=70&Itemid=82">Las Vegas</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab'+ddmenu_name.value)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being able to refer to an id directly in script was an old IE hack that is not standard, you should use `document.getElementById` instead.

Change:

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab'+ddmenu_name.value)">
```

To:

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(document.getElementById('ddmenu_name').value,'newtab')">
```

Also, IE (at least IE8) doesn't support an *equal sign* in a window name (this will result in a script error), so you'll have to find something safer to use - such as the index of the selected value:

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(document.getElementById('ddmenu_name').value, 'NewTab_' + document.getElementById('ddmenu_name').selectedIndex)">
```

I'm not sure if this is an IE thing or a standard browser thing.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EEta8/)

Comment: Also, what can I add to it so that the "Select Game" option isn't clickable? Right now if you hit 'go' it brings back a blank page.

Comment: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EEta8/1/) - Please click the "Accept" box if I've helped you, thanks!

Comment: Thanks again!  This is a great help.